# SimpleBlobDetector opencv python error but missing output

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, blob

I am trying to work with the opencv SimpleBlobDetector.
My current program is a simple test program like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

im = cv2.imread("blobs.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

params.filterByArea = True;
params.minArea = 1;
params.maxArea = 1000;

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)

keypoints = detector.detect(im)

im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

code runs until the keypoints line where it should actually detect the blobs. it doesnt show any error message but just restarts the kernel. i used a very easy picture so blobs should be detected.

[used image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V38r5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me. If you are using Python 3 you want to use `detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)` rather than what you had before. I increased the max area to `10000` pixels and I've included a screenshot of the output too:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

im = cv2.imread("blobs.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

params.filterByArea = True;
params.minArea = 1;
params.maxArea = 10000;

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

keypoints = detector.detect(im)

im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: output]

Comment: If you are using Python 3 you want to use detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params). That one did the job. thanks a lot.